# Pandas: how to read from markdown string?

Tags: python, pandas, markdown

I have a table on a git issue which has data about weekly workers.

The table written with markdown, and is like:

```markdown
start | end | main | sub   
-- | -- | -- | --    
1/30 | 2/6 | Alice | Bob   
2/6 | 2/13 | Charlie | Dave
```

I can get the current date, and can get that markdown text from rest api.

What I get from rest api is a string, which separates lines with `\r\n`.

And what I wanna do more is to figure out the weekly workers, but I'm stuck on this.

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: have you tried this? arr = [[x for x in ss.split('|')] for ss in str.split('\n')]

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further applications, I think you should form the table become records with each record as a dictionary whose key is the columns' name.

First, get headers of the table by:

```py
tableStr = 'start | end | main | sub'\
    + '\r\n' + '-- | -- | -- | --'\
    + '\r\n' + '1/30 | 2/6 | Alice | Bob'\
    + '\r\n' + '2/6 | 2/13 | Charlie | Dave'

headersStr = tableStr[:tableStr.find('\r\n')]
headers = [h.strip() for h in headersStr.split('|')]
```

then, parse the table to records by:

```py
records = []
for rowStr in tableStr.split('\r\n')[2:]:
    row = [entry.strip() for entry in rowStr.split('|')]
    record = {headers[i]:row[i] for i in range(len(headers))}
    records.append(record)

print(records)
```

you would get in console:

```
[{'start': '1/30', 'end': '2/6', 'main': 'Alice', 'sub': 'Bob'}, {'start': '2/6', 'end': '2/13', 'main': 'Charlie', 'sub': 'Dave'}]
```

I'm not sure about how you define `weekly worker`, but you could do something with it. For example:

```py
reverseSortedBySub = sorted(records, key=lambda x: x['sub'], reverse=True)
print(reverseSortedBySub)
```

then you'd get:

```
[{'start': '2/6', 'end': '2/13', 'main': 'Charlie', 'sub': 'Dave'}, {'start': '1/30', 'end': '2/6', 'main': 'Alice', 'sub': 'Bob'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer reading them via pandas, then you can do a lot more:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

tableStr = StringIO('start | end | main | sub'\
    + '\r\n' + '-- | -- | -- | --'\
    + '\r\n' + '1/30 | 2/6 | Alice | Bob'\
    + '\r\n' + '2/6 | 2/13 | Charlie | Dave')

df = pd.read_table(tableStr, sep="|", header=0, skipinitialspace=True).dropna(axis=1, how='all').iloc[1:] 
df
```

Output:

```
start   end   main      sub
1/30    2/6   Alice     Bob
2/6     2/13  Charlie   Dave
```